# How to logout of Auth basic authentication with htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, http-authentication

I'm doing HTTP basic authentication via .htaccess, and I need to logout; is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: [Here][1], @BalusC, describes a way to log out using Basic auth.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786807/logout-from-web-app-using-tomcat-basic-authentication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the Wikipedia [Basic access authentication page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) (in the Disadvantages section):

> there is no effective way for a server to "log out" the user without
>   closing the browser.

This is because the server doesn't keep track of who is logged in.  Instead, the browser sends authentication credentials on every request to the server.